# R Plot Steep Slope Curve

Tags: r, plot

I want to draw a curve which has very steep gradients at the Cartesian coordinates `x=0` and `x=1`.

I tried to generate weighted plot points according to its slope.
But I did not succeed.

[image]

---

**Code for above plot**

```
# Plot points weighted for gradient (My attempt)
ll <- stats::rchisq(100, 1)
lll <- 0.99 + ll
l <- append(ll, lll)

# Definition of curve
x <- 1 - exp(-l)
y <- 1 - stats::pnorm(0.3*stats::qnorm( exp(-l) ) - 0.5)

# Curve through precisely at (x, y) = (0, 0) and (1, 1)
plot(x, y, xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1))
```

---

**My desired plot**

[image]

---

**Edit**

Using the answer of @TavoGLC, I could do almost perfect plot. In my package, the number `0.3` and `0.5` in the definition `y <- 1 - stats::pnorm(0.3*stats::qnorm( exp(-l) ) - 0.5)`
  changes so, in the following I use `0.13` and `0.19` instead of the `0.3` and `0.5`.
[image]

Comment: If you combine `x <- c(0, x, 1)` and the same for `y` you will get close to that graph.

Comment: Thank you @RuiBarradas, but it only adds two points `(0,0)` and `(1,1)`. I want to add the sufficient points of the neighborhood of `(0,0)` and `(1,1)`

Comment: Maybe `seq(0, min(x) - 0.01, length.out = 10)` instead of `0`? And the same from `max(x)` to `1`.

Comment: Thank you @RuiBarradas, but it did not work, since it adds the negative 9 points. Even if, I can add the positive points, I think it cannot plot the connected curve. But from your reply, I think I have to plot a line which connects `(0,0)` and `(min(x), min(y))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that changing the weigths to a logarithmic wiight you can get a better approximation of the intended graph. The domain range is divided in three regions, the extreme regions are weighted with `logspace` generated values and the middle section is weigthed with `linspace`generated values.

```
library(pracma)
l0<-logspace(-15, 0, 25)
l2<-linspace(0, 1.5, 25)
l3<-logspace(0,3, 25)

la<-append(l0,l2)
l<-append(la,l3)
# definition of curve
x<- 1-exp(-l)
y <- 1-stats::pnorm(0.3*stats::qnorm( exp(-l ) )-0.5)

plot(x,y,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,1))
```

[image]

You can change the lower and upper boundaries from `logspace` or `linspace`to get a better result. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-D  I have  been bothered this plot issue for almost 2 years. And your answer let me free form this issue, thank you :-)  It helps me very much,